# Clicking on cancel on Javascript Confirm box does not stop the grid from refreshing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to stop the page from rendering the `.cs` code on click of cancel button on javascript confirm box?

I have a button click event and in some `IF` condition I am asking the user to confirm. Now when the user clicks on OK button, I have to bind the new data in a grid. but if the user clicks on cancel button, it should not refresh the grid with new data.

Question: On click of cancel button on JavaScript confirm box, how can I stop the following code to be executed, or how can I just return/break from JavaScript?

Can anyone please help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

**Markup**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" Enabled="false" OnClick="btnCopy_Click" ValidationGroup="Copy" />
```

**Code**

```
public void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (Convert.ToInt32(hidId.Value) > 0) {
        string scriptString = "<script language='JavaScript'> ";
        scriptString += "if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed?') == false) {return} ";
        scriptString += "</script>";
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("Confirm", scriptString);
        BindDataGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your existing code please.

Comment: Does `if (confirm("...")) refreshData();` not work?  Can you show us some code?

Comment: if (confirm("...")) refreshData();..it work if the user click OK..my question is how do i break when the user click on cancel button

Comment: @rick schott has it right below.  You are mixing client/server.  In the example above, you are setting the client onClick event in an event that takes place after the client click happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing server and client side code in the same event, it has to be separated:

**Script:**

```
function Confirm()
{
    var record=confirm('Are you sure to proceed??');
    if(record == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(record == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" Enabled="false" 
    OnClick="btnCopy_Click" OnClientClick='return Confirm();' ValidationGroup="Copy" />
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if (Convert.ToInt32(hidId.Value) > 0) {      
        BindDataGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: ..sorry i forgot the script..thanks..it works..thanks rick schott..u r awesome!!

Comment: Hey,

I am trying to wrap this in a $(document).ready(function () {

));

so that i can check for var value = document.getElementById("hidId"); and if value > 0 only than ask for confirm else return;
any tips on this??

Comment: something like this..
 $(document).ready(function () {
var value = document.getElementById("hidId");
alert(value);
if (value < 1)
return;
$(".confirm").click..
 function Confirm() {    
        var record = confirm('Are you sure you want to overwrite records?');
        if (record == 1)
        { return true; }
        else if (record == 0)
        { return false; } 
    } 

));

<div>
 <asp:Button class="confirm" ID="btnFillSIC" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick='return Confirm();' OnClick="btnFillSICData_Click" Text="Fill" Width="50px" />
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to catch the response, for example:

```
if (window.confirm)
{
//handle the OK
}
else
{
//handle the cancel
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this ....string scriptString = "<script language='JavaScript'> "; scriptString += "if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed?') == false) {document.execCommand('Stop'); } "; scriptString += "</script>"; Page.RegisterStartupScript("Confirm", scriptString);   and also window.stop()

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code, but without seeing your code I would guess you are not returning the response?

```
<input type="button" onclick=" return confirm('is this right?'); ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `return`  from the code or `exit(0)`.

```
function fillGrid()
{
 if( confirm("....") )
 {
  //populate your grid
 }
 else
 {
   return;
 }

 //do anything after the grid is populated
 //and exit the function
}
```

Comment: This is what i have <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" Enabled="false" OnClick="btnCopy_Click" ValidationGroup="Copy" /> public void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (Convert.ToInt32(hidId.Value) > 0) { string scriptString = "<script language='JavaScript'> "; scriptString += "if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed?') == false) {return} "; scriptString += "</script>"; Page.RegisterStartupScript("Confirm", scriptString); BindDataGrid(); }

Comment: Try to replace return with exit(0), it should do the job.

Comment: if(confirm("Are you sure to proceed?") == false) { exit(0); }

Comment: if i change it to this <script language='JavaScript'> if (confirm('Are you sure to proceed?') == false) {exit(0); } 
I get javascript runtime error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Comment: \You can just stay with return then, after it the script is finished and the control returns back to ASP callback. what more you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the confirm dialog in the codebehind of your button click, that wont stop the flow of your code.

You need to show the confirm dialogbox before do the postback

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" Enabled="true" OnClientClick="return confirm('sure?');" ValidationGroup="Copy" />
```